# Why tf is not linked on indigo?

Tags: ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've the problem that on ROS indigo **tf** is not linked to my executable even if I specify it in find_package and as dependency in package.xml.

Below is a stripped down example that shows the problem.

On ROS Hydro the package compiles fine.
On ROS Indigo i get the linker error: **undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'**

This are the only files in the package:

tf_broadcaster.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
    return 0;
};
```

CMakeLists.cpp:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tmptest)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf
)
add_executable(tf_broadcaster src/tf_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>tmptest</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The tmptest package</description>
  <maintainer email="a@b.cd">me</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
</package>
```

If I take a closer look at ${catkin_LIBRARIES}, libtf.so is not contained on Indigo, but it is on Hydro. Is this a bug or am I missing something that has changed from Hydro to Indigo.

Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197069/why-tf-is-not-linked-on-indigo?/) by [gernot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20746/gernot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't know what went wrong, but I could finally solve this by removing the build and devel folder and reinitialize my workspace. Thx!

---

Originally posted by [gernot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20746/gernot/) with karma: 16 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem.
Try putting anothe include in your code:

```
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
```

and in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package( catkin REQUIRED
    genmsg
    tf
)
```

I think there is another step too but I didn't remember right

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3